# How to use generic types correctly in HOC components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, high-order-component

Here is my parent component (Grid), (here I pass more props used by hoc but I ommited them here):

```
<QuickBooksTable itemList={quickBooksList} />
```

Here is the table component:

```
export const QuickBooksTable = withIntegrationTable(props: : WithIntegrationTableChildProps & WithIntegrationTableProps) => ...
```

Here is the hoc:

```
export function withIntegrationTable<T extends WithIntegrationTableProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
return (
    {
      itemList,
      ...props
    }: WithIntegrationTableProps & T
  ) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<WithIntegrationTableState>({
      tableItems: new Array<any>(),
      selectedItems: new Set<string>(),
      isAllItemsSelected: false
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      const tableItems = mapItemList(itemList, currentUser);
      setState({
        ...state,
        tableItems
      });
    }, [itemList]);

    <Component {...props as T}
               tableState={state}
    />
  }
}
```

But when it compiles it says:`Element QuickBooksTable doesn't have required attribute (here is another props name)`.
How should I use the types and generics to remove this error? I've tried to read the docs but I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: pls share reprooducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian, isn't it reproducable enough? what can I add to make the question more understandable?

Comment: Try to copy the code from your question to any sandbox

Comment: @captain-yossarian, sorry, it can't be done there are hundreds of files, and all the logic is linked, it will take a few hours to get the code you need

Comment: just share minimum reproducable example

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you try to achieve.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface WithIntegrationTableProps {
    itemList: string[]
}

interface WithIntegrationTableState { }

export const withIntegrationTable = <P extends WithIntegrationTableState>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P & { 
        tableState: WithIntegrationTableState
    }>
): React.FC<P & WithIntegrationTableProps> => ({
    itemList,
    ...props
}: WithIntegrationTableProps) => {
    const mapItemList = (itemList: any, currentUser: any) => {

    }

    const [state, setState] = useState<WithIntegrationTableState>({
        tableItems: new Array<any>(),
        selectedItems: new Set<string>(),
        isAllItemsSelected: false
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const tableItems = mapItemList(itemList, null);
        setState({
            ...state,
            tableItems
        });
    }, [itemList]);

    return <Component {...props as P} tableState={state} />
}

export const QuickBooksTable = withIntegrationTable(({ ...props }) => {
    console.log(props.tableState)
    return <div>
        test
    </div>
})

const App = () => {
    return <QuickBooksTable itemList={[]} />
}

export default App
```